# Status KPI indicatir

Tags: sharepoint-online, view

I am trying to set up a dashboard based on a SharePoint list so it shows the number of items in the list closed (green) number overdue (red) and number not yet due (amber)
I have created views of the list to show the 3 cuts of data that would give this  but want a simple traffic light to show our position
I could do this easily in SP 2013 but understand this had been discontinued for SP 2016 online
Any ideas how to achieve now please ?

Answer (score 1):

One way to provide an overview, be it on a single task list or across the site/site collection/tenant could be to create a custom search display template. This template will enable you to use any graphic you like

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example about creating Status KPI list for your reference:

[Color Coding Lists in SharePoint 2013, 2016, or Office 365](https://www.dmcinfo.com/latest-thinking/blog/id/8932/color-coding-lists-in-sharepoint-2013-2016-or-office-365)